# Is１人 always ひとり?

Tags: readings, counters, idiomaticity

This sentence appeared in [Mainichi](https://mainichi.jp/articles/20210821/k00/00m/040/127000c) the other day:

[1人]【ひとり】のために[10人]【じゅうにん】の未来【みらい】をつぶしていいんですか

Is it okay to destroy the future of ten people for the sake of one person?

Is the reading of 1人 in this case really【ひとり】?

[Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/1%E4%BA%BA) gives a number of other choices, and I figure they must be good for something:

[１人]【ひとり】
独り【ひとり】
一人【いちにん】
[１人]【いちにん】

Comment: Is there some reason you doubt that it's ひとり?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is written with the Arabic numeral, then yes, it should be ひとり.

[A dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%BA/m1u/) lists three readings for 一人

1. いちじん : the Emperor
2. いちにん : the same as ひとり
3. ひとり : one person

(See the link for precise meanings)

I think 1 and 2 are not in use today. So as long as you are dealing with modern texts, you can assume 一人 is ひとり.